# Postgres Partition Performance Tuning

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, database-partitioning

Select query scans all the child tables. can we make the query-optimizer to scan the right child table?

**Example:**

Created a parent table and two child table using the inheritance concept in Postgres 9.6, ignored constraints to make it simple

```
create table student(id INTEGER, name varchar(10), result varchar(1) );
create table student_pass() inherits (student);
create table student_fail() inherits (student);
```

**Index**

```
create index student_result_idx on student (result);
create index student_result_idx2 on student_pass (result) where result='P';
create index student_result_idx3 on student_fail (result) where result='F';
```

**Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION student_partition()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (new.result = 'P')THEN
        INSERT INTO student_pass VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO student_fail VALUES (NEW.*);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON student
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE procedure student_partition();
```

**Insert**

```
insert into student values
(1,'aaa','P'),
(2,'bbb','F');
```

insert happens in their respective tables as expected

**Select**

```
 select * from student where result='P';
```

The problem here is when I do select it scans all the tables. How to make the query-optimizer smart enough to pick the right child table?

Do we need the where condition in the index as the entire table is going to be either 'P' or 'F'?

**Output of** `EXPLAIN(analyze, buffers) select * from student where result='P'`

```
Append  (cost=0.00..37.94 rows=11 width=50) (actual time=0.016..0.042 rows=2 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4
  ->  Seq Scan on student  (cost=0.00..2.30 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.015..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((result)::text = 'P'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on student_pass  (cost=4.17..12.64 rows=5 width=50) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((result)::text = 'P'::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=1
        Buffers: shared hit=2
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on student_result_idx2  (cost=0.00..4.17 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Seq Scan on student_fail  (cost=0.00..23.00 rows=5 width=50) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((result)::text = 'P'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning time: 0.447 ms
Execution time: 0.120 ms
```

Comment: "*ignored constraints to make it simple*" - constrains would be very important for the query optimiser

Comment: If you really think you need partitioning for performance reasons, upgrade to Postgres 12 and use declarative partitioning. But I seriously doubt a table named `student` would ever benefit from partitioning to begin with. How many rows can it possibly contain? 1 million? 5 million? Neither of them indicates a size where partitioning would help.

Comment: For example, I mentioned as `student`, the actual table grows around 1 billion per month.    we are achieving the data, still, there will be around 3 billion records in a given time. we are trying to improve the performance of **select** without application-level changes.

Comment: If you expect 3 billion rows, then you should most definitely upgrade to Postgres 12 and use declarative partitioning. Forget about the old inheritance based partitioning. But partitioning will only help with performance if the queries include the partition key in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Adding constraints helps

```
alter table student_pass add constraint pass_cst check (result ='P');
alter table student_fail add constraint fail_cst check (result not in ('P'));
```

**Output of** `EXPLAIN(analyze, buffers) select * from student where result='P'`

```
Append  (cost=0.00..23.00 rows=6 width=50) (actual time=0.299..0.303 rows=2 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=1
  ->  Seq Scan on student  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((result)::text = 'P'::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on student_pass  (cost=0.00..23.00 rows=5 width=50) (actual time=0.294..0.296 rows=2 loops=1)
        Filter: ((result)::text = 'P'::text)
        Buffers: shared read=1
Planning time: 10.488 ms
Execution time: 0.361 ms
```

Query-optimiser skipped student_fail table